# vim jump forward with <c-i> doesn't work for me too (snipmate)

Tags: vim, snipmate

I have the same problem as many others users. Jump back `<C-o>` works, but jump forward don't.
I read same questions and answers but don't get any result.
I try `:verbose map <C-I>` command and get this:
[image: verbose command result]
How to disable snipmate mappings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, if that isn't clear to you, `<C-i>` is the same as `<Tab>`; unfortunately, you cannot map them separately.

You screenshot shows that *snipMate* has grabbed `<C-i>` in visual and select mode; it needs those mappings to jump to the next snippet tab stop. You can change that by editing the snipMate file, but these mappings **do not** interfere with the normal-mode `<C-i>` mapping that you're concerned about.

In normal mode, you've remapped `<C-i>` / `<Tab>` to `gt` in your `.vimrc`; you need to re-assign or remove that to get back the original `<C-i>` command.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer. I don't know that `<C-i>` equal to `Tab`. I disabled `Tab` in my vimrc and now it's all right.

Comment: I had the same problem. I was not sure how to disable Tab in my .vimrc. To inspect the mapping use :map <Tab> . then to clear it use :unmap <Tab> and the jumping should start working. For me I had this in my .vimrc nmap <Tab> >>
Removing this resolved the problem for me.